# Will the component re-rende if selectors change third time?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

For this selector code：

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import { FilterTypes } from '../constants'

export const selectFilterTodos = createSelector(
[getTodos, getFilters],
(todos, filters) => {
  switch(filters) {
    case FilterTypes.ALL:
        return todos;
    case FilterTypes.COMPLETED:
        return todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed)
    default:
        return todos
  }
}
)
```

If the redux state change from state one to state two and then return state one, how many times will the selector’s second function param run？
Maybe it‘s twice，and then will you want the selector to reuse the memorized result when state two to state one？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reselect's `createSelector` has a default memoization size of 1.  So, if you call a selector with:

```
someSelector(state, "a");
someSelector(state, "b");
someSelector(state, "a");
```

It will re-run the "output selector" 3 times.  The first time there is no cached value, and the second and third times the inputs are different, so it will not use the cached value.

If you need to change the memoization behavior, you can use `createSelectorCreator` to customize the comparisons and the caching.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to refer to the createSelectorCreator, and read some more docs.